# If $f\in L^\infty(0,1;H_0^1)$, then $\int_0^1fds \in H^1_0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Suppose that  $f\in L^\infty(0,1;H_0^1(\Omega))$.

Is it then true that $\int_0^1f(s)\,ds\in  H_0^1(\Omega)$?

($\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ is a bounded domain, $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space obtained as the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in the  $H^1$-norm).

The only thing I could prove is that $\nabla\int_0^1f(s)\,ds:=\int_0^1\nabla f(s)\,ds\in L^2(\Omega)$, as
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega \left(\int_0^1\nabla f(s,x)\,ds\right)^2dx&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_\Omega\nabla f(s,x)\nabla f(s',x)\,dx\,ds\,ds'\\
&\le\int_0^1\int_0^1\|\nabla f(s)\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\|\nabla f(s')\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\,ds\,ds'\\
&\le \|\nabla f\|_{L^\infty(0,1;H^1(\Omega))}^2.
\end{align}

Comment: This ought to follow from general properties of the Bochner integral.

Comment: @HansEngler I know little about Bochner integration. Do you mean that $\int_0^1\|f(s)\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}ds<\infty$ implies that $\exists f_n\in \text{Simple}(0,1;H^1_0(\Omega))$ such that  $\|f_n(s)-f(s)\|_{H^1} \to 0$ for a.e. $s\in(0,1)$, and $\|f_n(s)\|_{H^1}\le g(s)\in L^1(0,1)$, implying  $H_0^1(\Omega)\ni\int_0^1f_n(s)ds\stackrel{H^1}{\to}\int_0^1f(s)ds$?

Comment: That's indeed the definition of Bochner integrability.